# Java 32bit Xmx vs java 64bit Xmx

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I am really confused with this.

Xmx according to the java docs, is the maximum allowable heap size.
Xms is the minimum required java heap size, and is allocated at JVM start.

On a 32 bit JVM (4GB ram), java -Xmx1536M HelloWorld gives a cannot allocate enough memory error.
On a 64 bit JVM (4GB Ram), java -Xmx20G HelloWorld works just fine. But I don't even have that much virtual or physical memory allocated.

So from this, I conclude that Java 32 bit is allocating the 1536M at JVM startup, but Java 64 bit is not.

Why? A simple Hello World should not need 1536M to run. I am just specifying that 1536M is the maximum, not that it is needed.

Explanations anyone?

Answer (score 21):

There is a distinction between allocating the memory and allocating the address space. The Oracle JVM is allocating the **address space** on startup to ensure the heap is contiguous. This allows for certain optimizations to be used with the heap.

If the allocation fails, then Java won't start... as you have seen. It isn't necessarily using that much memory, but it is allocating the required address space up-front. Since you are passing `-Xmx1536m`, it is saying ok, I need to allocate that in case you need it... and since it must be contiguous it does it up-front so it can guarantee it (or fails trying).

This behavior is the same on both 32-bit and 64-bit JVMs. What you are seeing is the 2GB per-process address space limitation of 32-bit processes (at least, on Windows this is the limitation - it may be slightly larger on other platforms) causing this allocation to fail on 32-bit, where 64-bit has no issues since it has much larger address space. But, you say, 1536m is less than 2GB, I should be good, right? Not quite - the heap is not the only thing being allocated in the address space, DLLs and other stuff is also allocated in the address space...so getting a contiguous 1536m chunk out of 2GB max on 32-bit is unfortunately very unlikely. I've seen values below 1000m fail on 32-bit processes with particularly bad fragmentation, and usually 1200-1300m is the max heap you can specify on 32-bit.

On modern OSes, [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (Address Space Layout Randomization) makes fragmentation of 32-bit process address space worse. It intentionally loads DLLs into random addresses for security reasons... making it even less likely you can get a big, contiguous heap in 32-bit.

In 64-bit, the address space is so large that fragmentation is no longer a problem and giant heaps can be allocated without issues. Even if you have 4GB of RAM on 32-bit, though, the 2GB per process address space limitation (at least on Windows) usually means the max heap is usually only 1300m or so.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, the application is not allocating the Xmx memory at startup.

The -Xms parameter configure the startup memory. ([What are the Xms and Xmx parameters when starting JVMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms))

The 64bit environment allows a bigger memory allocation then 32bits. But, in fact, it's using the HD space, not the memory ram.

See this other post for more info.

[Estimating maximum safe JVM heap size in 64-bit Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219301/estimating-maximum-safe-jvm-heap-size-in-64-bit-java)

Comment: +1 You can do `java -Xmx3g` for 32-bit Linux, it's Windows 32-bit which has limited continuous address space.

Answer (score 3):

Under Windows there is a difference in memory allocation operations with native WinAPI low-level functions like VirtualAlloc.

"Reserving" means allocation of a continuous area within process' address space without actually making this area of virtual memory usable. Allocated area is not backed by actual physical RAM or swap space and does not consume any free memory. Any application can reserve any amount of address space limited only by processor's memory addressing capability (bitness).

"Committing" means backing some of previously "reserved" memory with real memory - RAM or swap space, making it actually readable/writable by the process. This memory is taken from available OS virtual memory pool (RAM and swap).

An alternative to "committing" memory (taking a blank page from the pool) is "mapping" a file into the previously "reserved" memory. This does not consume memory from the swap pool but uses the mapped file in a manner similar to a dedicated swap space for that specific region of a process' address space.

Native Windows applications (like JVM itself) reserve memory for all heaps needed in the future, but commit it only as needed.
High-level memory operations like malloc() style functions or "new" operators really do "commits" as needed or even do their own heap management logic user-mode with memory committed ahead by large chunks as it is'a CPU-intensive kernel call and works at page (4k) granularity.

During process startup JVM "reserves" -Xmx memory, but "commits" only -Xms amount of it. The remaining reserved memory is committed on demand as heaps grow. So heaps can grow up to available memory or -Xmx parameter, whichever is smaller.