# Why doesn't WebStorm launch if I change VM options

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've changed VM options in `~/.WebStorm2016.3/webstorm.exe.vmoptions` through `Help -> Edit custom VM options` menu to the following:

```
# custom WebStorm VM options

-server
-Xms740m   <----------------
-Xmx3050m  <----------------
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

After that, WebStorm is not launching. Why?

Comment: *"After that, WebStorm is not launching. Why?"* because Java (JVM?) is unable to allocate that much memory (which needs to be done in 1 solid chunk .. which is very problematic on 32-bit). If you need that much memory (3GB) -- use 64-bit JDK and 64-bit WebStorm launcher.

Comment: 1) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241105-The-JVM-could-not-be-started-The-main-method-may-have-thrown-an-exception 2) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Comment: thanks, but I have both 64bit webstorm and JDK - `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)`. However, it seems that `open JDK server vm is used`. Don't know how to check it's bit

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under ... or just use 2017.1 EAP build -- it comes with and uses 64-bit JDK by default. if anything -- check `idea.log` for details (or Help | About) -- it should have bit info there

Comment: Alternatively: 1) `Help | Find Action...` 2) Search for `Switch IDE boot JDK...` and run that action 3) Do the needed changes there

Comment: thanks, _it comes with and uses 64-bit JDK by default_ - which JDK? Java's or Open JDK by Jetbrains? You can post your comments as an answer. They are very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After that, WebStorm is not launching. Why?

That's because Java (JVM?) is unable to allocate that much memory (3GB; which needs to be done in 1 solid chunk .. that's is very problematic when using 32-bit JDK).

Better switch to using 64-bit JDK and 64-bit WebStorm launcher which can handle such situations if you need that much memory.

If you need more info on that -- please check this StackOverflow question and those that offered in Related section: [Java 32bit Xmx vs java 64bit Xmx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262911/java-32bit-xmx-vs-java-64bit-xmx) .

Other links to the actual JetBrains' articles on this/related subject:

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241105-The-JVM-could-not-be-started-The-main-method-may-have-thrown-an-exception
- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

---

If you do not know how to start using 64-bit WebStorm, please check [this arcticle](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) or just use [2017.1 EAP build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP) -- from 2017.1 JetBrains IDEs come with and use own 64-bit JDK by default.

If anything -- check `idea.log` for details (or `Help | About`) -- it should have bit info there.

Alternatively:

1. `Help | Find Action...`
2. Search for `Switch IDE boot JDK...` action (typing just `jdk` should be enough to have that action preselected) and run that action
3. Do the needed changes there