# OpenJDK errors java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space and Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap

Tags: java, out-of-memory, 32-bit, visualvm, adoptopenjdk

The team switched from Oracle JRE 1.8 to OpenJDK. Started the test with this version:

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8-Ø.372
```

Things were OK until load testing started and moved to a higher staging environment. The team started getting the following errors:

Cannot start the application with -Xmx1024m:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap
```

Then, change the JVM memory parameter to -Xmx512m (or kill some unwanted background services/tasks on Windows Server), the application will start successfully and then start throwing the following errors halfway through load testing:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

There is the following restriction: must use JRE 32-bit version 1.8.0_341 or lower since the JDK used was based on 1.7. The 32-bit is due to using other components that don't work with 64-bit.

I have done extensive research, and came across various articles including this one:

[Difference between JVM and HotSpot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568253/difference-between-jvm-and-hotspot)

Note that the application has been working for years, without any error, with Oracle's JRE 1.8 update 341.

I have the following troubleshooting plan:

1. Switch between OpenJ9 and HotSpot OpenJDK

OpenJ9: https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/semeru-runtimes/downloads/
HotSpot: https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=8

2. Try a lower or higher version of OpenJDK since there is no one-to-one mapping between the Oracle JRE version and that of OpenJDK.
3. Try other GC Algorithms based on this article:

https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/11/02/how-choose-best-java-garbage-collector

5. Submit a ticket to Redhat support.

I need your help to find other troubleshooting options, and in particular, how to use Java tools to start profiling and memory debugging to see what is going wrong.

---

## Update 1:

In the following, I will provide info about the OpenJDK and other details.

- When running `java -version -XshowSettings:properties` I get the following:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_372"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_372-b07)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.372-b07, mixed mode)

Property settings:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
    file.encoding = Cp1252
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = \
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
    java.class.path = .
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372-1\jre\lib\endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372-1\jre\lib\ext
        C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
    java.home = C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372-1\jre
    java.runtime.name = OpenJDK Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_372-b07
    java.specification.maintenance.version = 4
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vendor = Red Hat, Inc.
    java.vendor.url = https://developers.redhat.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi
    java.version = 1.8.0_372
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = OpenJDK Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Red Hat, Inc.
    java.vm.version = 25.372-b07
    line.separator = \r \n
    os.arch = x86
    os.name = Windows Server 2019
    os.version = 10.0
    path.separator = ;
    sun.arch.data.model = 32
    sun.boot.class.path = C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372-1\jre\lib\resources.jar
        C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372-1\jre\lib\rt.jar
        C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372-1\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar
        C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372-1\jre\lib\jsse.jar
        C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372-1\jre\lib\jce.jar
        C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372-1\jre\lib\charsets.jar
        C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372-1\jre\lib\jfr.jar
        C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372-1\jre\classes
    sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372-1\jre\bin
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86
    sun.desktop = windows
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level =
    sun.stderr.encoding = cp437
    sun.stdout.encoding = cp437
    user.country = US
    user.dir = C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372-1\bin
    user.language = en
    user.script =
    user.timezone =
    user.variant =
```

Does this mean that I am using HotSpot OpenJDK?

- Following are the OS details:

```
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum CPU @ 2.20GHz 2.19 GHz (16 processors)
Installed memory (RAM): 64.0 GB
System type: 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
Pen and Touch: Pen and Touch Support with 10 Touch Points
```

- I installed VisualVM and watched a couple of tutorials. I think I have a plan. I will get a dump of the JVM parameters, use profiling/sampling/snapshots/heap dump, and then compare the differences between OpenJDK and Oracle JDK. I will also use to option to create a heap dump when the OutOfMemeory exception is thrown.

  Any Idea how to use VisualVM effectively to find a resolution for this issue?

Comment: Since it's pretty important in this case: 32 or 64 bit? Also, how are you invoking java? And of course: how much free memory is there when you try run java?

Comment: This is where I need help for troubleshooting or debugging. Since it's 32-bit JRE on Windows, this means, only 1.5 GB will be available in the first 4GB block or at least this is my understanding. The server has a more than 10GB free RAM, yet it's throwing the errors as mentioned in the question. I can't use 64-bit as of now. Java is started using the command line as usual.

Comment: Remember to put that information in the post, not just a comment. Also please explain what the server is (at the very least enough specs to cover the aspects that are relevant to the JVM), because that's still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

There is space limitation for 32-bit process. Each process can use up to 2GB. (Refer [another SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21264320/4838367))

You can use OpenJ9 JVM from IBM (still IBM support 32bit version for Java 8) which can significantly reduce overall memory footprint and you can start your application. [JDK Link](https://github.com/ibmruntimes/semeru8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u382-b05_openj9-0.40.0/ibm-semeru-open-jdk_x86-32_windows_8u382b05_openj9-0.40.0.zip)

Comment: Thank you. The link you gave me, is a well-kept secret. I couldn't figure out how to reach such a link!